# How to specified multiple attributes in the findscu command

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

All, Forgive me I am a newbie in the DICOM world. I tried to learn the DCMTk tools to talk with PACS server. But didn't found much tutorial or sample in the internet to know enough about it .Currently I just have the [offical document](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/findscu.html) to read.

I just tried the findscu.exe to test c-find command .

I remembered C-Find would return what specified in the request message. for example. If I only specifed the condition `Patient Name ='abc'` then the reponse would return only attribute `Patient Name`. Nothing else.( If it is not right . Please correct me.)

So I want to know how to return all the attribute of response DICOM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> How to specified multiple attributes in the findscu command.

Just specify multiple --key (-k) options on the command line. Alternatively, you could also use a "query file" as described in the man page.

> So I want to know how to return all the attribute of response DICOM.

Then, you have to specify all attributes (keys) you are interested in. That's how C-FIND works.

By the way, if you are querying a PACS (Query/Retrieve SCP), then you also have to specify the Query/Retrieve Level (0008,0052), e.g. "PATIENT".

> Currently I just have the offical document to read.

If you think that the [examples](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/findscu.html#notes) in the man page of the findscu tool are not sufficient (and you are actually querying a PACS), [this HOWTO](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_PACSDebuggingWithDCMTK#Querying-a-PACS-with-findscu) might be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally legal to send a request with `Patient Name` information only and the PACS will return all matching datasets.
Each dataset should at least contain all mandatory fields like `Date of Birth`, `Patient ID`, and so on, depending on the `Query Level`.

What information is returned by the PACS system on each `Query Level` should be specified in the `DICOM Conformance Statement` of the vendor. I would recommend to take a look at this to know, how to set up a valid query to get the information you need and/or if the information is provided by the PACS system.

Comment: Actually, The query is against on the `dcm4chee`. It seems it will response what I feed to it. for example. like what I said in the post .only patient name return . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to include the Unique key and Required Key Attributes in the request attribute list. Also, include the optional attributes (if supported by SCP) when you wish server to return values for them. Please refer to DICOM Standard PS 3.4 section C.2 and C.3 detail information on Query/Retrieve service. List of attribute and type (Unique, Required, Optional) is listed section C.6.1.1.2 (Patient Level), C.6.1.1.3 (Study Level) and so on.